# How to change a rows background color in Slickgrid, if a certain cell is not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I want to change the entire rows background color if a certain cell in that row is not empty. I have been strugling with adding a custom formatter but no results.

Answer (score 0):

Proved to be more difficult than I thought it would.

Anyway, assuming columns with `field` values of 0,1,2,3, & 4 you can do the following:

```
 var colNeedingData = 2; // Column "C" (row headings are ignored in the index)

 function cellNotEmptyFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {

   if (dataContext[colNeedingData] && dataContext[colNeedingData] != '') {
     var rowCells = {};        

     rowCells[row] = {
       0: "highlight",
       1: "highlight",
       2: "highlight",
       3: "highlight",
       4: "highlight"
     };

     grid.setCellCssStyles("highlightRowWhenNotEmpty" + row, rowCells); // add row# to make a unique key
   } else if (dataContext[colNeedingData] == '') {
     grid.removeCellCssStyles("highlightRowWhenNotEmpty" + row); // add row# to make a unique key
   } 

   if (value)
       return value;
   else
       return '';
 };
```

With the column definitions something along the lines of

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  columns.push({
     id: i,
     name: String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i),
     field: i,
     width: 100,
     editor: Slick.Editors.Text,
     formatter: cellNotEmptyFormatter
  });
}
```

This will give every cell in the row a `highlight` class when data is present in the 3rd column (column "C" in the jsfiddle below).

Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/gftqzyj5/

Comment: If you feel that this answer answers your question could you consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to it, thanks